Exponential dichotomy
Given a real symmetric matrix $A$ of size $n$ having a spectral gap at the $k$-th eigenvalue: $\lambda_1\le\ldots\le\lambda_k<\lambda_{k+1}\le\ldots\le\lambda_n$; denote $A^-$ the restriction of the matrix $A$ to the eigenspace relative to the $\lambda_1\le\ldots\le\lambda_k$ and $A^+$ the restriction relative to $\lambda_{k+1}\le\ldots\le\lambda_n$ (easily done by composing $A$ with the corresponding projections, since the eigenspaces provide a direct sum). Show that there exist a constant $C$ such that $\Vert e^{A^-t}\Vert\le Ce^{\lambda_k t}$ for all $t\ge 0$ and $\Vert e^{A^+t}\Vert\le Ce^{\lambda_{k+1} t}$ for all $t\le 0$.
Apparently this is a standard fact used in dynamical systems but I am unable to prove it, due to the fact that all inequalities I know would end up with the absolute value of the eigenvalues, not with the eigenvalues themselves, after a few estimates... I suspect that in my source the results is stated while omitting a crucial hypothesis that all eigenvalues are positive. But even if this is the case, only the first bound seems straightforward, the second still remains problematic for me.

Let $A$ be a real symetric matrix. 
$(i)$ The matrix $e^A$ is diagonalizable. Moreover, an eigenvector for $A$ is an eigenvector of $e^A$ and vice versa. 
Indeed, if $\Omega$ is an orthogonal basis in which $A$ is diagonalizable, write $A=\Omega D \Omega^{-1}$. Then $A^n = \Omega D^n \Omega^{-1}$ for every $n$. Thus, we have $$e^A = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{1}{n!} A^n = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{1}{n!} \Omega D^n \Omega^{-1} = \Omega \Big( \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{1}{n!} D^n \Big) \Omega^{-1} = \Omega e^D \Omega^{-1},$$ which is of course diagonalizable, as $e^D$ is the diagonal matrix, which diagonal entries are the exponential entries of $D$. 
$(ii)$ For $M$ a matrix, note the spectral radius $\rho(M) = \textrm{sup} \ |\lambda(M)|$, where $\lambda(M)$ means an eigenvalue of $M$. I will for now on assume that we work over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\| \cdot \|$ be a norm, and let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis. Let $M$ be a matrix which diagonalizes in $\mathcal{B}$. Then there exist $C>0$ such that for every matrix $M$ which diagonalizes on $\mathcal{B}$, we have $$\| M \| \leq C \rho(M).$$ Be aware that $C$ depends on the norm $\| \cdot \|$ and $\mathcal{B}$ ! 
Indeed, we know that every norm are equivalent are equivalent in finite dimension (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), thus, for whatever basis $\mathcal{B}$, there existe $C>0$ such that $\| \cdot \| \leq C \| \cdot \|_{\infty,\mathcal{B}}$. Let $\mathcal{B}=(e_1,\dots,e_n)$, and $M$ which diagonalizes on $\mathcal{B}$. Then it is straighforword to check that $\|M\|_{\infty,\mathcal{B}} \leq \rho(M)$. Thus, we have $$\|\cdot \| \leq C \rho(M).$$
Now we can easily conclude. Both matrix $A^{-}$ and $A^{+}$ are real and symetric, thus diagonalizable. Moreover, if $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of eigenvectors of $A$, then they are diagonalizable in $\mathcal{B}$. By the point $(i)$, if $t\in\mathbb{R}$, then $e^{tA^{-}}$ and $e^{tA^{+}}$ are diagonalizable in $\mathcal{B}$. The eigenvalues of $e^{tA^{-}}$ are $e^{t\lambda_1},\dots,e^{t\lambda_k}$. If $t>0$, by exponential positivity and growth, you we have $$0 \leq e^{t\lambda_1} \leq \dots \leq e^{t\lambda_k}.$$
Thus $\rho(e^{tA^{-}})=e^{t\lambda_k}$. 
Similarly, if $t\leq 0$, then $\rho(e^{tA^{+}})=e^{t\lambda_{k+1}}$. 
Let $C>0$ be the constant of point the $(ii)$ (which only depends on $\|\cdot \|$ and on $\mathcal{B}$ !). Then, by point $(ii)$, we have $$\|e^{tA^{-}} \| \leq C e^{t\lambda_k} \textrm{ for } t\geq 0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \|e^{tA^{+}} \| \leq C e^{t\lambda_{k+1}} \textrm{ for } t\leq 0.$$

Thank you so much for the answer. Just a confusion, since I have never met the notation. By $\Vert M \Vert_{\infty,\mathcal{B}}$ do you mean $\Vert V^{-1}MV \Vert_{\infty}$? Here $V$ is the matrix having for columns your $e_i$.

You're welcome :)
By $|M|{\infty,\mathcal{B}}$, I mean $\underset{i,j}{\textrm{sup}} |\lambda{i,j}|$, where $\mathcal{B}=(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ and $Me_i = \sum_{j} \lambda_{i,j} e_j$. This is like the infinite norm for the canonical basis.

Maybe I misunderstood something: are $e_i$ eigenvectors of $M$ by construction ('$M$ diagonalizes on $\mathcal{B}$' does not mean that?) or the canonical basis of, say, $\mathbb{R}^n$?

First, I define $|\cdot|_{\infty,\mathcal{B}}$ for any basis, and lemma $(ii)$ is true for any matrix $M$ for which element $\mathcal{B}$ are eignevectors, wich is the same as to say that $M$ diagonalizes in $\mathcal{B}$. 
Then, I set $\mathcal{B}$ a basis of eigenvectors of $A$, and I apply the lemma to the matrixes $e^{tA^{-}}$ and $e^{tA^{+}}$, which are always diagonalizable in $\mathcal{B}$ (by lemma $(i)$).

So your notation refers to what I call the $\max$-norm, you just vectorize the matrix (the matrix representation of the map in the basis $\mathcal{B}$, whatever it is) and do the infinity norm of that vector. Then that's smaller than the standard euclidean operator norm, which is the spectral radius. So ii) is also true for any basis $\mathcal{B}$, not just made of eigenvectors, as long as $M$ is diagonalizable. With eigenvectors, you get equality to $\rho(M)$ right?

Oh yes, there is the equality between $|M|_{\infty,\mathcal{B}}$ and $\rho(M)$ when $M$ is diagonalizable in $\mathcal{B}$. And you are right, there is no need to introduce this max norm, the euclidean does the job, as we have symetric matrix. What I proved is then a bit more general but a bit mor messy for your need, you are right.

No worries, I like your answer a lot anyway. Last doubt: your $A^+$ and $A^-$ are $(n-k)\times (n-k)$ and $k\times k$ matrices right (i.e. they are the coresponding representation of $A$ restricted to the corresponding subeigenspaces in the corresponding eigenbases)? Otherwise they would have also a bunch of zeroes, and thus the exponential of them would have also a bunch of eigenvalues $1$ to consider.

You are right. To get ride of this problem, you can apply the point $(ii)$ two times ; you know that there exist two constant $C_{-},C_{+}$, such that $| e^{tA^{-}}| \leq C_{-} e^{t\lambda_k}$ for all $t\geq 0$, and $| e^{tA^{+}}| \leq C_{+} e^{t\lambda_{k+1}}$ for all $t\leq 0$. Then the constant $C=max(C_{-},C_{+})$ does the job.
